# Subject verification of certificates

Tags: tls, cryptography, digital-signature

Suppose H has taken C’s certificate and manually changed the subject information in C’s certificate from C to H. Would this modification be detected by A during the certificate verification process?

Answer (score 2):

The data in the cert is hashed and the hash is sighed with C's private key. C's public key is in the cert. All of this is hashed and signed by a CA's key. Changing the subject changes the hash, the new cert is bad without even verifying the first signature.

Comment: Exactly.  If someone tries to change any information in the certificate after it's been signed by the CA, this would break CA's digital signature of the certificate.